# Is DevCon.exe still the best way to restart/power cycle USB ports after resuming from hibernation in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a USB broadband card on my Windows 7 laptop.  It loathes resuming from hibernation properly.  Back in the XP days I would issue a call devcon.exe from the command prompt and restart the selected ports (Saves you having to manually unplug and plug back in your USB devices).

Ive been trying this is Windows 7, but the UAC keeps getting in the way.  I'll start a command prompt.  Issue the devcon command, but UAC asks me if I really want to do this, when I click yes it opens a different command prompt and launches the command.  After the command completed this new prompt window closes faster than the speed of light and I cannot see the results.  So Im thinking there has to be a better way to do this in the Vista/Win7 world...?

---

Edit: Ive found with the [Microsoft Application Compatibility Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=24DA89E9-B581-47B0-B45E-492DD6DA2971&displaylang=en) and this tutorial (www.vista4beginners.com/Disable-UAC-for-certain-applications) I was able to disable UAC for specific applications. This solved my devcon closing problem, but after solving that issue I realized that devcon is broken for 64-bit Windows 7 on a x86 architecture....  So there still is no way to restart a usb port it looks like.... Hrmgh!

Comment: have you tried it from an *elevated* command prompt?  i can't recall the procedure for getting one offhand but i'll let someone else post the details, but i think that's what you want.

Comment: To be honest, I disabled UAC. I can't see any value in it.

Comment: Does NirSoft USBDeview solve your problem? At least that utility is available for x64... See http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html

Answer (score 1):

Run CMD elevated:

Start Menu-All Programs-Accessories rightclick on "Command Prompt" and select "Run as administrator"

Although i have to admit i didnt get Devcon to work either on Win7.It correctly found all hardware and their strings but every time i tried to disable/enable any device the command would fail even with elevated command prompt.
So atleast for restarting my network connection i use this now:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" disabled
choice /T 5 /D y > nul
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" enabled
```

Where "Local Area Connection" is the name of the connection to be restarted and "choice" is for waiting(depends on adapter...some disable fast but others don't so its better to wait a little).I have no idea how to restart usb ports without Devcon tho.

Comment: Does `choice` exist in Win7? As I recall, it didn't come with any previous WinNT version.

Comment: Are you running 64-bit windows in a x86 processor?  Ive been reading that devcon is broken for this architecture (works for ia64 though)

Comment: comment by TMRW: @grawity - Yes choice is included by default.

Comment: comment by TMRW: @ProfessionalAmateur - Indeed i am running 64bit Windows 7.As far as the CPU goes that should not be a problem since my old AMD Athlon X2 3800+ SOC939 is 64bit capable. Although if Devcon simply isnt compatible with x64 then it would explain quite few things. Still i wander tho - it's possible to disable a device from Device Manager so there must be some undelying funtion for this even on x64.